# Intervalos de tiempo entre registros

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, time

Tengo una tabla que se compone de la siguiente manera:

> **Horarios**
>
> ```
> id int(11) pk uq nn ai
> inicio datetime nn default "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
> fin datetime null default "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
> tipo tinyint(1) nn default 0
> eliminado tinyint(1) nn default 0
> ```

El hecho es que estos horarios corresponden a distintos usuarios y quería buscar una forma de saber si algunos de los mismos coinciden con otros horarios de usuarios del sistema

En un principio, creí que con un "BETWEEN" se solucionaría:

```
SELECT inicio, fin FROM horarios
WHERE eliminado = 0 AND tipo = 0
BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2018-01-10','06:30:00') AND TIMESTAMP('2018-01-10','12:30:00')
```

Pero MySQL me está devolviendo casi cualquier fecha que encuentra en la tabla (varias de otros días inclusive)

¿Hay alguna forma de poder obtener el resultado que busco?

**Nota 1**: Utilizo PHP (rotando entre la v5 y v7 para revisar compatibilidad), MySQL como gestor e InnoDB como motor.

**Nota 2**: Dejo un ejemplo claro, porque tal vez mi forma de explicar es bastante mala:

> *Inicio*: '2018-01-12 13:30:00'
>
> *Fin*: '2018-01-12 19:30:00'

Lo que se requiere, es el conjunto de horarios que se encuentren en esa franja horaria (por más que compartan al menos 1 minuto). Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está realizando la consulta mal, debería ser:

```
SELECT inicio, fin FROM horarios
WHERE eliminado = 0 
AND tipo = 0
AND ((inicio BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2018-01-10','06:30:00') AND TIMESTAMP('2018-01-10','12:30:00'))
OR (fin BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2018-01-10','06:30:00') AND TIMESTAMP('2018-01-10','12:30:00'))) ;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta.
Probé la consulta y no devuelve ningún valor. He intentado cambiar el rango a consultar sin obtener ningún registro (aclaro, por si acaso, por el momento tengo 20 registros y 3 de ellos concuerdan en algunas horas con el consultado). Inserté un nuevo registro con los datos precisos que consulto y allí si obtengo resultados, pero no es lo que requiero en este caso (más bien, quiero obtener todos los registros que se encuentren dentro de esa franja horaria [de 06.30 a 12.30]).

Comment: ¿Sin importar que la hora que concuerde sea la de inicio o la de fin?

Comment: Exacto. De hecho, requiero los registros que tengan alguna coincidencia: si un horario comienza a las 12.00 y termina a las 13.31 debería devolverlo en la consulta (comparte un minuto con el indicado arriba). No sé si me explico...

Comment: Modifiqué la respuesta, tal vez con el OR pueda dar el resultado que espera

Comment: Gracias nuevamente.
Te comento que he probado la consulta y funciona realmente. Estaba esperando para saber si había alguna otra forma más "económica" pero como funciona y es estable, la tomo como correcta. Muchas gracias :).